# What do you call a verb/phrase following a noun ending in 'er'

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech

Is there a term for the verb, and/or the pair of words, where the verb ends in 'er' following a noun?

Examples:

- mind reader
- star gazer
- grounds keeper

Comment: 'Reader', 'gazer' and 'keeper' are _agent nouns_. 'Mind reader' etc is a compound noun. I assume that makes 'ground keeper' etc compound agent nouns.

Answer (score 0):

Nouns that are formed from verbs like this (i.e., through derivation with a suffix such as -er) are called **agent nouns**. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun):

> In linguistics, an agent noun (in Latin, *nomen agentis*) is a word that is derived from another word denoting an action, and that identifies an entity that does that action. For example, "driver" is an agent noun formed from the verb "drive".

Comment: If 'agent noun' is the answer, this is an obvious duplicate.